# SSRS: how to conditionally change ability to drill though based on value?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an ssrs summary report, which drills though to a detail report.

Depending on the data, certain tablix cells could possibly have no values in them.
I have to keep them visible due to formatting constraints.

It doesn't make sense for the user to be able to drill though from these value-less cells.

Is there any way to conditionally change that ability to drill though based upon the value of a tablix cellor dataset field? If how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just choosing a report to drill through, click the function button. 
[image]

You can enter an iif statement like

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value), Nothing, "DrillthroughReportName")
```

or

```
=Iif(Fields!MyField.Value = 0, Nothing, "DrillthroughReportName")
```

Comment: Thanks keep forgetting about nothing rather than null